# Memory Leak in sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm getting a leak when trying to create a CGSize to set the correct height for the UILabel. I also receive the same leak while setting the height in heightForRowAtIndexPath.

This is the code snippet that is leaking:

```
CGSize size = [news.news sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(230.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

                UILabel *newsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 50, 230, size.height)];
                newsLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];
                newsLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
                newsLabel.text = news.news;
                newsLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
                newsLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
                newsLabel.textColor = COLOR_DARK_GRAY;
                newsLabel.highlightedTextColor = COLOR_WHITE;
                newsLabel.backgroundColor = COLOR_CLEAR;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:newsLabel];
                [newsLabel release];
```

Here is the leak that's listed in the leaks instrument:

Leaked Object: icu::UCharCharacterIterator
Responsible Library: WebCore
Responsible Frame: WebCore::LineBreakIteratorPool::take(WTF::AtomicString const&)

Also a different leak that points to the same line:

Leaked Object: icu::UCharCharacterIterator
Responsible Library: WebCore
Responsible Frame: WebCore::acquireLineBreakIterator(unsigned short const*, int, WTF::AtomicString const&)

If there's anything else I could provide I'd be happy to do so. I've confirmed by commenting out that single line above (the creation of CGSize size) that it's the line that's leaking. Occurs on both simulator and device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have access to the `WebCore` code, nothing to be done. Your code looks fine to me. There are numerous small leaks in Apple's libraries that you sometimes just need to accept will not go away.

Answer (score 1):

In your statement `newsLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];` you create an `UIFont` object that is to be autoreleased. But if your code runs in a thread without an autorelease pool explicitly set up using `@autoreleasepool {}`, this object will never be released (because no autorelease pool exists), and will leak.
So, if your code runs indeed in a separate thread, check if you have set up an autorelease pool.

Comment: This is not the problem in this case. The OP's leak is not of a `UIFont` object.